# Collision with walls does not apply when changing ball location

Tags: c#

I've been working on a Breakout-style project recently and wanted to make it so that once a user enters the 'cheat mode', they'll be able to move the ball in their desired direction.

Here's what my code looks like: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7589f4f141888c3c32c7

I've included the `return;` in my ball class due to the fact that if I don't, the program will not recognise the changes in the X and Y. So basically, my problem is, I want the program to ignore the existing x and y speeds and use the ones provided by the user if the cheat mode is enabled. (Meaning if the user enters the cheat mode, the program should stop the ball where it last was, in terms of x and y coordinates, and let the user move it)

Example of what I mean:

Player enters cheat mode -> Presses Up.
 - Ball keeps moving up until it hits the top of the form and then should bounce back in the opposite direction to which it hit the wall.

How do I implement this into my program? I used the 'if statement' for the boolean cheat mode and the return function to exit the `moveBall` procedure (which ignores the xSpeed and ySpeed but ultimately stops the ball from moving on it's own completely, so the player has to keep clicking `Up` to move the ball up, otherwise it stays in place.

EDIT:

Okay, I've fixed the issue where the ball wouldn't move, I just added a few more variables for the X and Y change of the ball.

Here's what my code looks like now:

```
public void moveBall()
{
    if (Form1.cheatModeClicked == true)
    {
        ballRec.X += cheatX;
        ballRec.Y -= cheatY;

    }
    else
    {
        ballRec.X += xSpeed;
        ballRec.Y -= ySpeed;
    }

}
```

However, the ball collision still doesn't want to work, and I don't know why?

Comment: Please see edit, I've altered my code slightly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to add a method to the ball class to allow the ball's speed to be set externally. Then you can call that method when keys are pressed, depending on the cheat mode state. The cheat mode state should be stored outside the ball class anyway. The ball itself should only know about ball things and not what a non-ball concept such as cheat mode is.

Here is some pseudo code, I might have missed a few things in the description but hopefully it helps

```
class Form
{
    bool _inCheatMode = false;
    Ball ball;
    void EnterCheatMode()
    {
        _inCheatMode = true;
        ball.SetSpeed(0, 0); //stop the ball
    }

    void ExitCheatMode()
    {
        _inCheatMode = false;
    }

    void KeyDown(Keys key)
    {
        if (_inCheatMode)
        {
            if (key == Keys.Up)
               ball.SetSpeed(0, -1);
        }
    }
}

class Ball
{
    public void SetSpeed(x, y)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I've managed to get the ball moving, it's just that the collision won't respond to the ball's movement. Will your example help solve this issue?

Comment: sorry I only just saw your code change. If you do it that way I think you will need to change the collideWall() method too. currently you are doing xSpeed *= -1; you will also need to do cheatX *= -1. and also cheatY *= -1 in the other place, because in cheat mode it is using cheatX and cheatY not xSpeed and ySpeed. Hopefully that will fix the collisions

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for pointing that out!! I think this may just solve my problem :)